# Alembic Primary Key issue with mssql ( Azure Synapse SQL DW )

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic, azure-synapse

Im trying to apply migrations using alembic to Azure Synapse SQL DW. Im facing following issue while performing `alembic upgrade head`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Enforced unique constraints are not supported. To create an unenforced unique constraint you must include the NOT ENFORCED syntax as part of your statement. (104467) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
        version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY (version_num)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

my version file is  :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '6c51cb206ea6'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'dqrule',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column('description', sa.String, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('source_type', sa.String, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('source_schema', sa.String, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('source_entity', sa.String, nullable=False)
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('dqrule')
```

Comment: You could try adding a line in the `[alembic]` section of alembic.ini that says `version_table_pk = false` and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson The setting doesnt seem to have any effect

Comment: see also: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/938

Answer (score 1):

A valid SQL statement for Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pool would be:

```
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
        version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (version_num) NOT ENFORCED
);
```

As per the error message, dedicated SQL pools do not support unique constraints but you can create them with the `NOT ENFORCED` keywords.  Clustered primary keys are also not supported so you have to add the `NONCLUSTERED` keyword.

You should probably also specify the distribution ( `ROUND_ROBIN` | `HASH` | `REPLICATE` ) and the index type ( `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX` | `CLUSTERED INDEX` | `HEAP` ) in a `WITH` clause, eg this statement will have the same outcome as the one above but is explicit and self-documenting:

```
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
        version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (version_num) NOT ENFORCED
)
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
);
```

The choices you make depend on the data volumes and usage best desrcibed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-index).  `ROUND_ROBIN` and `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX` are the defaults.  Consider crafting these statements instead of using a framework if the framework will not give you the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the creation of the primary key on the alembic_version table by doing the following:

Edit env.py and add the `version_table_pk=False` option to the `context.configure()` call in the `run_migrations_online()` function. That is, this …

```py
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )
```

… becomes this

```py
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata,
            version_table_pk=False
        )
```